# Using Gemalto Prox-SU reader with NDEF messages in NTAG203

Tags: nfc, mifare, ndef, pcsc, gemalto

I have an app using ACR122U and NTAG203. I have no problem to read or write NDEF messages with ACR122U.

My clients are expanding and I'd like to change all platforms to use Prox-SU.

I acquired a Prox-SU to test. Almost all works well except when reading NTAG203.

With NTAG203, the Prox-SU is identifing my tag as MIFARE Ultralight. So,  I am able to read only until page (block) 0x0F according to documentation of Prox-SU. But I have data saved above of page 0x0F because my tag is really a NTAG203 (41 pages in total).

When I use ACR122U reader, I have no problem to read or write to this tag and I can read beyond page 0x0F.

I have been searching for support, but it has been too hard to find technical support from Gemalto.

Is it possible to use NTAG203 with Prox-SU to read pages above 0x0F?

Comment: I had the same issue with an Omnikey 5321 and eventually gave up.

Comment: Thanks, May I ask you what reader are you using now?

Comment: Various versions of the ACR122U with all their problems.

Comment: Mr Michael Roland, do you have experience with ACR122U in Linux Arm platform?

Comment: No, I don't have any experience with that.